# Why is my redux store not immutable?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

I currently am using react-redux and Immutable.js. I've just realized that each field in my store is of an immutable type. However, when I console.log the store, it's actually an object, where the values are of immutable type. The store itself, is still an object.

I create a custom function called `configStore`, where I use `compose` to add middleware, devtools, etc. Then I call `configStore` to actually create my store, which takes an empty object as the initial state. When I console.log my store, I get something like this:

```
Object {
  keyA: Map(),
  keyB: OrderedMap(),
  ...
}
```

This seems contradictory to what I've been doing throughout my app, where selectors take in the entire state to obtain data in the store. For example, I'll do something such as `(state) => state.keyA.getIn(nestedKey, furtherNestedKey)`. `getIn()` is an ImmutableJS API.

This leads me to few questions that are worrying me:

- If `state` was an object, as shown when I console.log the store, how can Immutable interacting with it?
- Is having a non-Immutable store (which contains Immutable data types), defeating the purpose of using Immutable and React-redux?

Comment: That code snippet (`state.keyA.getIn...`) implies that Immutable is **not** interacting with the outer object.

Comment: `Immutable.js` is *not* the only way to make JS objects immutable. You can also use `freeze()` what I think redux is doing in its `combineReducers`. Using immutables is not needed at all though. That's just a helper for keeping *you* from mutating the data.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ah. You are absolutely right. Are there any downsides though? It doesn't seem right that my store is an Object with Immutable types.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, that's the whole point of immutable. So shouldn't the outer object also be immutable?

Comment: @AlanH You can make them immutable. You are the one calling `combineReducers` and you can convert that result to an immutable if you so desire.

Comment: @Sulthan I'm referring to the outer object.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable only provides an immutable version of the most common set of data structures such as `List`, `Map`, `Set`, etc. It doesn't interact with the state directly, instead you can use its data structures in some properties of the state, for example, to store a collection of objects. You should use Immutable so you can manipulate these data structures without mutating the state. Take as an example the following code, assuming you have an action that returns an array of articles:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

reducer = (state = {
  articlesLoaded: false,
  articles: Immutable.List(),
}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "GET_ARTICLES":
      return { 
        ...state, 
        articlesLoaded: true, 
        articles: Immutable.List(action.articles) 
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The purpose of using Immutable is purely convenience, as it makes it easier to avoid mutation in data structures. Of course you can have an store that is not an Immutable data structure, in fact that's the most common use case. It is important to note that the immutability of an object doesn't depend on the object itself, but on the way you manipulate it (you don't, you create a new one), so you can also mutate the state while using Immutable if you really mess things up.

If you wan't to go all in with Immutable [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable) has a modified version of `combineReducers` that uses Immutable data structures, so you can have the entire state defined as an `Immutable.Map`.